# JSON-simple:JSONArray Usage Error

Tags: java, json

I've a JSON Array:

```
JSON_STRING = [{"name": "adminparking1", "id": 1},{"name": "adminparking2", "id": 2}]
```

And I Want to parse it to a JSON-simple Array and work with json Objects that it provides from it examples I do it this way:

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    Object res_obj = jsonParser.parse(JSON_STRING);
    JSONArray json = (JSONArray) res_obj; //(HERE Error Occurs)
```

It gives me this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

how can i get rid of this error?

Comment: What should `JSON_STRING = [...` tell us? This is not valid Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works just fine, if JSON string is valid

```
public static void main() throws ParseException {
  String JSON_STRING = "[{\"name\": \"adminparking1\", \"id\": 1},{\"name\": \"adminparking2\", \"id\": 2}]";
  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
  Object res_obj = jsonParser.parse(JSON_STRING);
  JSONArray json = (JSONArray) res_obj; // no Error
  System.out.println(json.get(1));
}
```

prints

```
 {"name":"adminparking2","id":2}
```

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSON_STRING);

  //loop through each object
  for (int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){

  JSONObject jsonProductObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = jsonProductObject.getString("name");
  String url = jsonProductObject.getString("id");
}
```

Comment: It is json-simple library not org.json,your example is org.json